# Select, выпадающий список, обработка без перезагрузки javascript

Tags: html, javascript

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, с такой задачей, есть выпадающий список типа

```
<select id="my_select" name="my_select">
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Нужно чтобы при выборе элемента списка, с строке JS-скрипта добавлялась строковая переменная, т.е. что-то типа

```
 var prog = $("#my_select option:selected").val();

 var path = "program" + prog;
```

я в JS не силён и поэтому не совсем понимаю как нужно сделать правильно, и обязательно условие страницу перезагружать не нужно.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: куда добавлялась ? `$('#my_select').change(function(){var value=$(this).val();});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну что за мода для каждого чиха и пука жквери всобачивать?..
Нативно - быстрее и правильнее:

```
var targetValue; // переменная, куда при изменении выбора списка уйдет его value

var sel = document.getElementById("my_select");
sel.onchange = function() {
    targetValue = sel.value;
};
```

Comment: document.getElementById("my_select").onchange = function() {
        targetValue = this.value;
    }

м, так же лучше?

Comment: В вопросе jquery так почему ответ должен быть не на нем же? Конечно нативно очень красиво но вопрос то был задан с примером.

Comment: @binliz а в тегах нет :)

Comment: да, с дыз лучше -- но я оставил более громоздко на понимание, поскольку ТС сам признался, что еще не готов :)

Comment: да jQuery не нужна, просто пока только в js разбираюсь, а пример с jQuery был рядом, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

как то так

```
var path="";
jQuery(document).on('change','#my_select',function(){
   path = "program" + jQuery(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш пример пригодится;)